# TwentyTwentyTwo - How to add PHP logic to Post templates?

Tags: theme-twenty-twenty-two

I'm testing out the new TwentyTwentyTwo theme for WordPress 5.9.
I can see that when I enter a post, on the right side I have the option to either Edit or Create New Templates.

[image]

In edit mode, it brings us into the edit view of that template (which kinda reminds me of a reusable block in a way..)

[image]

**But how do we "edit and save" PHP code for these templates?**  Like loops, actions, do_actions, etc... I don't see the templates being auto generated in my Visual Studio Code environment anywhere....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But how do we "edit and save" PHP code for these templates? Like loops, actions, do_actions, etc... I don't see the templates being auto generated in my Visual Studio Code environment anywhere....

**You don't**, these are block templates, not PHP templates. When in the filesystem in a theme they are plain `.html` files, and when you modify or create them in the user interface they're saved in the database.

In order to run PHP code in these templates you would need one of the following:

- a custom block that renders in PHP
- a custom shortcode inserted via a shortcode block

This is the same as asking how to run PHP inside a posts content, and the solutions are the same. Custom blocks and shortcodes.

Comment: Understood. So is this completing replacing the traditional way of creating custom post type templates in child theme directories?

Comment: Both yes and no, and neither, and both. Look up universal themes and hybrid themes, as well as full site editing and block themes. If you want to you can consider block themes the new way of doing things and that is the future, but there's a lot of inbetween stuff and shades of gray where you're neither fully classic or fully block based. Also keep in mind that child block themes exist too

Comment: Tom thanks for the tips on this. I'll begin my journey in these places.